# How to grep word, exclude this word from the string

Tags: grep

I need to find all strings, that contain "foo", but exclude this "foo"

```
grep "foo" | grep -ve "foo" return zero strings
```

Example input:

```
"category": "aaaa",
"amount": 0.01208210,
"vout": 0,
"fee": 0.00007523,
"confirmations": 12345,
"blockhash": "12345",
"blockindex": 12345,
"blocktime": 12345,
```

On output I need just:

0.01208210

Comment: Show some sample input and corresponding desired output.  As it stands (you want to search for `foo` but exclude `foo`), the question is unclear.

Comment: for example: Line1: bbbbb "foo" : 12345  Line2: ccccc "foo" : 32145          On output I need just 12345, 32145     "foo" is the same on all strings

Comment: In your case, you can just do something like: `$ awk -F: '/foo/{print $NF}' file`. But with more information, we could give you a better answer.

Comment: Your actual question is probably: _print the second column if the first column contains the word "foo" in a column-separated-file_

Comment: no, its not a second column...

Comment: Misha, the update is very helpful.  Thank you.  @kvantour's solution (with `foo` replaced with `fee` as per the new example) works for me.

Comment: It's works!!! ) Thank you, @kvantour!!!